# Laravel Auth::user() returns null except for login function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working on a Laravel 8 project with Inertia.js. In the login function, I can use Auth::user() to get the user. However, after login, the other functions get a null in Auth::user(). I'm not sure what's wrong. Can someone help me?

I considered that Laravel Auth uses sessions to recognize the current user, so I tried to list session by `dd($request->session()->all());` before and after login. And the session value of "_token" does not change.

**Login function**

```
public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request)
{
    // user from socialite
    $user = \Socialite::with('portal')->user(); 
    
    // user here in database
    $account = User::where('account', $user->id)->first(); 
    if (!$account) {
        User::create([
            'account' => $user->id,
        ]);
        $account = User::where('account', $user->id)->first();
    }

    Auth::login($account);
    //dd(Auth::user());

    return Inertia::render('Home/index');
}
```

**function which gets null**

```
public function getUser(Request $request)
{
    dd(Auth::user());

    return Auth::user();
}
```

Here is some information that may or may not is needed.

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/login', 'Auth\PortalLoginController@redirectToProvider')
    ->name('login');
Route::get('getUser', ['as' => 'getUser', 
    'uses' => 'Auth\PortalLoginController@getUser']);
Route::get('session', ['as' => 'session', 
    'uses' => 'Auth\PortalLoginController@listSession']);
```

**auth.php**

```
return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
    ],
    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],
    'password_timeout' => 10800,
];
```

Comment: Sorry for my poor English and thanks to those who help me.

Comment: Are your routes or controllers under auth middleware?

Comment: No. But I've tried to let it under auth middleware. However, it always redirects me to example.com/login even I've already login.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel needs `auth` middleware to check authentication and initialize Auth service. So you need to add `auth` middleware to all your routes which you want to access `Auth::user()`

So update your routes in `routes/web.php`

```
Route::get('/login', 'Auth\PortalLoginController@redirectToProvider')->name('login');
Route::get('getUser', ['as' => 'getUser', 'uses' => 'Auth\PortalLoginController@getUser'])->middleware('auth');
Route::get('session', ['as' => 'session', 'uses' => 'Auth\PortalLoginController@listSession'])->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: I've edited it. However, when I access https://example.com/getUser (Already logined). It redirects me to https://example.com/login. Seems like I did not login.